# TypeScript infer second argument of a function first argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

Is it possible to infer a function argument from another argument? I want to infer 2nd argument based on inference of 1st argument.

Current code can be on GitHub [slickEventHandler.interface.ts](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/common/src/interfaces/slickEventHandler.interface.ts) and is the following

```js
export type GetSlickEventType<T> =
  T extends (infer U)[] ? U :
  T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U :
  T extends SlickEvent<infer U> ? U : T;

export type GetEventType<T> = T extends infer U ? U : T;

type Handler<H> = (e: SlickEventData, data: GetSlickEventType<H>) => void;

export interface SlickEventHandler<T = any> {
  subscribe: (slickEvent: SlickEvent<T>, handler: Handler<T>) => SlickEventHandler<T>;
  unsubscribe: (slickEvent: SlickEvent<T>, handler: Handler<T>) => SlickEventHandler<T>;
  unsubscribeAll: () => SlickEventHandler<T>;
}
```

and this allows me to do the following (live code [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/0b4d8b1070485721b96446eef2fbca3c724f30f0/packages/common/src/services/gridState.service.ts#L579))

```js
const onSelectedRowsChangedHandler = this._grid.onSelectedRowsChanged;
(this._eventHandler as SlickEventHandler<GetSlickEventType<typeof onSelectedRowsChangedHandler>>).subscribe(onSelectedRowsChangedHandler, (_e, args) => {
  args.column;
});
```

and this does proper inference

[image]

However, what I'm looking for is a much simpler approach as shown below (but what I currently get using the code below is `args` being infered as `any`)

```js
this._eventHandler.subscribe(onHeaderCellRenderedHandler, (_e, args) => {
  const column = args.column;
  const node = args.node;
});
```

So as I mentioned in the question, for that to work, I would need to infer first argument and somehow make an alias that can be used by the second argument. Is that possible with latest version of TypeScript?

Comment: pls provide reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the methods to be generic not the interface, so you would put the generic at the function definition not the interface name.

```
export interface SlickEventHandler {
  subscribe: <T>(slickEvent: SlickEvent<T>, handler: Handler<T>) => this;
  unsubscribe: <T>(slickEvent: SlickEvent<T>, handler: Handler<T>) => this;
  unsubscribeAll: () => this;
}
```

then the generic will be inferred when you call the method.

Comment: yeah that's a bit better but that is still is not the short syntax that I'm looking for, I still have to type the event twice (or use a variable which is still count as 2). `this._eventHandler.subscribe<GetSlickEventType<typeof this.grid.onScroll>>(this.grid.onScroll, (e, args) => { /* ...*/ });` and by the way, in your demo it can't return `<T>` anymore since you removed it from the generic, so it should simply return `SlickEventHandler` and I agree that `unsubscribeAll` should probably return nothing. My question still stand, is it possible to infer fn 2nd argument from 1st argument?

Comment: does not specifying the generic not work? like try `this._eventHandler.subscribe(this.grid.onScroll, (e, args) => { /* ...*/ });` it should resolve the generic based on the input arguments. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "in your demo it can't return `<T>` anymore since you removed it from the generic" I removed it from unsubscribeAll but it is still valid for the other 2.

Comment: oh wow you're right, I didn't realize it was actually doing a full inference, sweet!!! As for the `<T>`, I meant the new output has to be `SlickEventHandler` not `SlickEventHandler<T>` because `<T>` is no longer provided as a generic to the interface (prior it was `interface SlickEventHandler<T = any> { }`  and now is `interface SlickEventHandler { }`, in other words it should be this `subscribe: <T = any>(slickEvent: SlickEvent<T>, handler: Handler<T>) => SlickEventHandler;`  (just remove `<T>` form output. The `SlickEventHandler` is pipeable and that is why it returns itself

Comment: oh I missed that it was returning itself (you had a lot of similarly named types) in that case shouldn't you just be returning `this` type instead?

Comment: yeah adding TS interfaces for an old JS lib is sometime confusing as well, I'm sometime out of ideas on interface names to use. Adding `this` as the return type is yet another great idea, I didn't even know we could use `this` inside an interface. Thanks for all the great suggestions, it makes my code so much more easy to use with proper inference.